# Using dir() at the top level within a class

Tags: python, class

Can you construct a Python function g such that when it is imported,

dir() == g()

returns True. This is really a question about the difference between importing 
and manually entering a function at the top level.  Many languages make some sort of distinction.  As the answer points out, there is a difference.  What is this difference and why?

Another answer is simply to paste the function g into the top level, leaving out the question of a startup file, which, of course also works.

This is my attempt to get back into the good graces of the "powers that be" who are threatening to banish me from question asking.  I have been thrown out of other places as well that did not want to support the First Amendment, but, of course there is an easy way back in.  The same comment appears below because I'm slow at finding the correct procedure.

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected output? Where is the relevant code?

Comment: "It works fine except for the default dir()" - that doesn't really make it clear what's going wrong or what problem you're trying to solve. You haven't showed us what you've done or even asked us a question. Whatever you're trying to do, we can't help you with this little to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To get the top level dir() affect within a class, load it upon startup, e.g., put the module in /.ipython/startup/.  The class then comes in at the **main** level.
With import it does not.  All obvious I guess, but not to the new guy.

Comment: It's a long time since I asked the question, and the powers that be are threatening to cut me off on questions.  This answer works, but my question is why?  Where in the documentation is the difference between the top level and importing explained?  I was accused of not asking a question, so here it is.  Is there a python function g so that when it is imported dir() == g() is True?